# Could not determine data type in SQL Like operator with params

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin, vert.x

I'm trying to write a "select" with a parameter inside "like" operator. This is my code:

```
val result = connection.queryWithParamsAwait(
    "select * from users where username like '%?%'",
    jsonArrayOf(query)
)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> could not determine data type of parameter $1

I suspect it is caused by the quotes, so I have also tried this:

```
val result = conn.queryWithParamsAwait(
    "select * from users where username like ?",
    jsonArrayOf("\'%$query%\'")
)
```

It doesn't crash but returns no results, and it should.

I'm using this client: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mysql-postgresql-client

Comment: `like '%' || ? || '%'`?

Comment: Or include the wildcards in the parameter itself ? `'%?%'` is a string with three characters, not a parameter value surrounded by wildcards. Parameters are *parameters* that are sent to the server to be used as ... parameters in the script. They aren't string substitution placeholders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the wildcards and the parameter:

```
like '%' || ? || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find that regular expressions are more convenient:

```
where username ~ ?
```

A regular expression matches anywhere in the string, so you don't need wildcards for the beginning and end.

This is fine if `?` only consists of digits and letters -- that is, if it doesn't have special regular expression characters.  However, it might be a feature that you have the power of regular expressions.